# AWS SDK EC2 - "DescribeInstances" Exception, skip instance in list

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, exception, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have a list of Instances ID saved in DB.
a periodic check validates those ID's against AWS.
The problem is that if one of the instances doesnt exist then i get Exception and the whole request fails (none of the ID's return).

Is there a way to skip that missing ID and get back all data except for that specific instanceID?

My code:

```
$requesltArray = ['Filters' => $this->_Filters, 'InstanceIds' => $this->_InstanceIDs];

try {
    $reservations = $this->_EC2Client->DescribeInstances($requesltArray)->toArray();
} catch (Ec2Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc;
    return [];
}
```

results in Exception:

> aws sdk Error executing "DescribeInstances" InvalidInstanceID.NotFound

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the number of instances you have, you might consider then to perform your DescribeInstances request for each individual IDs.

```
$reservations = [];
foreach($this->_InstanceIDs as $anInstance){
    try {
        $requesltArray = ['Filters' => $this->_Filters, 'InstanceIds' => $anInstance];
        $aReservation = $this->_EC2Client->DescribeInstances($requesltArray)->toArray();
        $reservations[] = $aReservation;
    } catch (Ec2Exception $exc) {
        // --> Delete the instance from your database?
        continue;
    }
}

dd($reservations);
```

Comment: Thanks, but not possible....i thought about this solution but in my Env its not a valid one

Comment: Can you tell me why it's not possible in your current environment? Is it due to the number of instances?

Comment: yeap, you got it :)

Comment: @DannyValariola if you wish to delete the invalid instance(s) from your records then a good option would be to keep the code you've put in your post and to retrieve the instance ID from the exception. I suppose there is a way to retrieve the ID from the exception? Worst case by manipulating the error message "Client.InvalidInstanceID.NotFound: The instance ID 'i-XYZ' does not exist" . And you loop on that.

Comment: yeap that is what i ended up doing. BTW the exception arose from an ID that was never on AWS (a made up testing one) and not with an obsolete id